# Create a Page Content type

Tags: content-type, custom-content-type

I am a newbie and need to create a `Page Content Type`.

How can I go ahead and do it? Also describe the significance of it.

Comment: What's the page type that you need to create - Article Page
- Redirect Page
- Welcome Page
- Publishing Master Page
- Page
- Page Layout

Comment: Publishing Master Page

Comment: are you work before with Design Manager ?

Comment: Nope I haven't but I have to start By tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from you at comments that I think it's not related to what you ask above, you need to create a master page in SharePoint 2013.

- So Before we begin, make sure you have your HTML template ready.
- Once you have your templates and Images upload the entire folder in your MasterPage Gallery.

Then follow the mentioned detail steps at

- [How to create HTML master page for SharePoint](http://borderingdotnet.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-create-html-masterpage-for.html)
- [Add an Html Master Page to SharePoint 2013 using Design Manager](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/03/25/add-an-html-master-page-to-sharepoint-2013-using-design-manager/)
- [Creating a New Master Page in SharePoint 2013](http://blog.navantis.com/creating-a-new-master-page-in-sharepoint-2013/)

If you stuck at any step please mention this at comments.

Answer (score 2):

Content type is a term similar to template

It is the collection of features common to similar types of files once they are uploaded to sharepoint, example the image content type (inside the picture library) is made up of several information, such as title, keywords, thumbnail author, date and time that are not present by default to other content types.

When it comes down to Page content types, I can recall off top of my head Wiki page, web part page, Project Page, Enterprise wiki page, article page, you can customize any of those adding fields ( =columns) with mandatory or optional information to fill in (example, you want to add a choice field to specify the department, you simply add a column to the existing content type). If you want to instead customize the areas of the page or add controls, this needs to be done with SPDesigner and you need to know coding.

Comment: Could there be a question which says What is the relationship between a Page and a Page Content Type?

Comment: It is the same relationship that there is between a Word template (example: invoice template) and the file itself (the invoice).

Comment: How to create a page content type?

Comment: I wrote it in my answer, adding fields is easy, creating a template from scratch you need to code.